# Run Junit Suite using Maven Command

Tags: maven, maven-2, junit, test-suite

I have multiple Junit test suites (SlowTestSuite, FastTestSuite etc). I would like to run only specific suite using maven command. e.g.

```
mvn clean install test -Dtest=FastTestSuite -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

but its not working. Just not running any test at all. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can run JUnit test suite from surefire plugin.

Comment: Still does not work used as: mvn test -Dtest=com.org.mysuites.FastTestSuite -DfailIfNoTests=false

Comment: You can run using surefire plugin that is working if you include it e.g.`<include>**/FastTestSuite.class</include>`. Its just a requirement to run it from command line using maven command.

Comment: No got an exception running `mvn clean test -Dtest=FastTestSuite` because its not picking up that suite so there is not test to run.

Comment: Just for info that all suites are under src/test/java/ (not sure if it matters).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I have achieved this by adding property into pom as:

```
<properties>
    <runSuite>**/FastTestSuite.class</runSuite>
</properties>
```

and maven-surefire-plugin should be:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${runSuite}</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

so it means by default it will run FastTestSuite but you can run other test e.g. SlowTestSuite using maven command as:

```
mvn install -DrunSuite=**/SlowTestSuite.class -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

Comment: I would like to add that the maven-surefure-plugin is a requirement, I found in some places saying that only with the property it'll work, but is not true.

Comment: Thanks **@Java SE**, your approach works perfectly with *Maven 3.3.3* and *JUnit 4.12*. But `**/FastTestSuite.java` can be used instead of `**/FastTestSuite.class`. Both variants perform fine, but specifying `.java` looks more consistent with official documentation (for instance, http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: When I add these settings my test suite runs but all other tests are excluded. If I don't add the settings all tests run but my test suite is ignored.

Comment: Minor addenda -- the `properties` element goes at the root of your `project` element (i.e. directly inside it, without being inside anything that's also inside `project`, a sibling of `dependencies` and `build` and so on). If you already have a `properties` element in your `project` root, _do not_ add another -- instead, just add the inner line (`<runSuite> ... </runSuite>`) to the existing one.

Answer (score 5):

The keyword you missed is maven-surefire-plugin :http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/.

Usage is :

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/com.your.packaged.Sample.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

If you make a little search on stack overflow, you may find information :

[Running a JUnit4 Test Suite in Maven using maven-failsafe-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792886/running-a-junit4-test-suite-in-maven-using-maven-failsafe-plugin)
[Using JUnit Categories with Maven Failsafe plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542530/using-junit-categories-with-maven-failsafe-plugin)

In addition, you may define profile, like fastTest, that will be triggered by adding parameter to cmd line :

```
mvn package -PfastTests
```

This profile would include some inclusions too.

Comment: As I said in my question that I need to run this using maven command. It is working the way you mentioned. I dont want to add profile basically.

Comment: Indeed, profile management IS the way to trigger different behaviour.