# What is the best way to run integration tests using a web server?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jetty, gradle

As the title says, I'm interested in the best approaches of testing an application using a Jetty web server, taking in consideration that you don't want to start/stop the test server for each particular test.

As far as I know, these are the solutions:

1. if you use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, you can do it in the `*.pom` or `*.gradle` file.

   - this has the disadvantage that you have to create the test server in a different way that you normally do it in the application.
2. Creating a test suite and using the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations to start/stop the server before/after the test `Suite`.

   - disadvantage here is the "ugly" way of specifying the tests to run. You also have to specify that the test which is added to the suite, it shouldn't run outside of the suite(avoid duplicate run of the test). I think Junit is not yet fully equipped for this.
3. Create and start the server in a static way at the beginning of the tests and use the `ShutDown` mechanism to hook up in the JVM and stop the server automatically when all the tests are completed. This seems to be the best solution because this mechanism is available in Jetty already, but

   - the disadvantage is that you are not in control of the stopping of the server. It is done actually in a totally different thread, even outside of the building tool(I use Gradle for this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do #2 for pretty much all of our tests in jetty itself.  It is really very easy to create an embedded server and deploy an app, or a servlet, or whatever you like in it.  This gives you more then just the ability to run automated tests but also a way to debug your application simply within an IDE, without all the tooling overhead of an ide.  So from the Jetty perspective we are big fans of creating your test suite and starting and stopping servers as needed within that test.  We have test cases where we spin up multiple servers and test session expiration between them, others where we spin up a server and toss 10k client connections against it with our async jetty-client.  Just running a complete build of jetty starts and stops hundreds of jetty server instances.

Not every app can be wired up like that, some have external database requirements and the like but even there you often have the ability to write unit tests against an in memory database like derby, which is an excellent approach to compartmentalizing your tests.  If you absolutely require an environment for running your tests then many folks have luck with a combination of maven, jetty-maven-plugin and things like selenium but I generally view these as more functional testing, or acceptance testing scenarios, actual unit testing should be done within the context of a junit test...imo at least.

Comment: How do you specify the tests to run in a suite? Using the `@SuiteClasses` annotation on the Suite, or a dynamic approach? Also, when you run the junit tests from IDE, beside the suite, also the actual tests will be run a second time. How do you ignore the actual tests, in order not to be run a second time? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: in jetty our tests are simply annotated with @Test and following a naming convention of FooTest.class, and then we use the maven surefire plugin to run them during normal builds.  Within the IDE like eclipse, you can just run the individual test if you want, or you can run the directory of tests.  If you have tests running twice I would say that is a configuration issue in the IDE itself more then anything.

Comment: Could be that I was not explicit enough. When I said Suite, I was referring to `org.junit.runners.Suite`. If you create a test with this annotation, the you have to specify the `org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses` annotation, which includes the test classes you want to add to the `org.junit.runners.Suite`. As long as the specified test classes are just normal junit4 tests classes, they will be run, even when they are run from maven. Maven doesn't know that these test classes are defined in a `org.junit.runners.Suite` annotation and will also be run by that junit runner.

Comment: So I was not referring to simple junit test classes, which have methods to test inside and can be annotated with `@Test`. I would like to have separate junit test classes and wrap them in a `org.junit.runners.Suite', in order to be able to start/stop jetty before/after the `org.junit.runners.Suite`. This way you can start the server once, run all the tests in a Suite and then stop the server. Additionally you can run other Suites. The main reason for this is the speed of the overall tests. Starting/Stopping the server, takes time.

Comment: oh, then you can do something like they mention in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762801/run-junit-suite-using-maven-command but really starting and stopping jetty on a per class or per test instance is not time consuming, though deploying your application might be which makes more sense to do it they way you mention.  anyway, just configure surefire to only run the suites, not the *Test classes.

Comment: I use Guice to bind everything together and then ask Guice for the Server. For the tests you can inject then different objects for the binding (like configuration etc).This way, the tests are following exactly the same pattern as in production.

Answer (score 1):

We use a Jenkins build pipeline using the [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin).   The first job kicks off the build and creates an artifact that includes all the compiled code, including a WAR file and all the test code compiled.

Then, a downstream job is kicked off which deploys the WAR file to a live Tomcat server.

Subsequently we have a job that runs integration tests (getting the tests from the test artifact from the upstream build) against the live Tomcat server.

There's more to it than that, but that is the general idea.