# Why Suite classes are not run but the other Tests

Tags: java, maven, testing

I have a set of integration tests which I need to run in specific order. So i created a `BlahSuite.java` inside the same package, and specified the order of classes there. And annotation as following

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
```

And I added the plugin into pom as following

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Suite.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But still the tests are fired in different orders, feels like the Suite class is fully ignored. Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at Stackoverflow question [Run Junit Suite using Maven Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762801/run-junit-suite-using-maven-command)

So what my final setup is I just removed failsafe plugin and added following,

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*Suite.class</include>
  </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```