# Maven Surefire Junit test suite

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire

I am using the Maven Surefire plugin in order to run just a specific suite of tests.
For instance:

```
package suite;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

import suite.slow.EvenSlowerClassTest;
import suite.slow.SlowClassTest;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    SlowClassTest.class,
    EvenSlowerClassTest.class
})
public class SlowSuite {

}
```

By using the maven command

```
test -DrunSuite=**/FastSuite.class -DfailIfNoTests=false
```

I can run the FastSuite or SlowSuite test suites explicitly, however, how can I run all test suites that I have or all tests that are not covered in a test suite?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>${runSuite}</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: `mvn test` will run all tests under `src/test/java` (I haven't downvoted BTW)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But if I have the include directive in the surefire plugin (I updated the question with the pom.xml) it runs a suite by default. If I do not add that include, I can't run any suites giving a parameter

Comment: Did you try with `-DrunSuite=**/*` ?

Comment: @CédricCouralet The property `runSuite` does not exist in maven-surefire-plugin see the documentation.

Comment: It's is a property that is included. @CédricCouralet that helped, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have done in some of our projects, is to use `<profiles>` in the `pom.xml` to activate special suites of tests. If no profiles are active, all tests will be run with `mvn test` (i hope that's what you are looking for)

Like so:

```
<profile>
    <id>commit-test</id>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>com.test.CommitTest</groups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Test classes in annotated like so:

```
@Category(CommitTest.class)
public class SomeTestClass {
}
```

I don't know if it works with `@Suite` and `@RunWith` but if your test suites aren't too many classes, it shouldn't be a difficult job to change that.

command: `mvn clean test -Pcommit-test`

Comment: Where does the Category annotation come from? I can;t find it within the junit framework

Comment: `junit-4.11` under `org.junit.experimental.categories`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with -DrunSuite=**/*Suite.class

Comment: There does not exist a property like `runSuite` in [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).

Comment: No property `runSuite` out-of-the-box, but it can be defined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762801/run-junit-suite-using-maven-command (accepted answer)