# How to run a specific unit test of a specific Test class of a specific Test Suite with Maven (JUnit 4)

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

I'd like to run a specific test routine called `T20` which is in the class `UploadTest` which is part of the test suite `TestSuite` (Junit4).
There is a @BeforeClass in my test suite that I need to run before running `T20`.

Is it possible to do this with maven and Junit 4 ? If not, is there any other test framework that allows it ?

I tried :

```
mvn test -DtestSuite=TestSuite -Dtest=UploadTest#T20
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried with maven surefire plugin? Check this http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen this page. It talks about running a unit test inside a test class but they don't explain how to do the same with test suites.

Comment: Workaround with profiles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009569/1230748

Comment: Thanks for the profile hint. It would certainly work. I used TestNG with various xml files instead and it fixed my problem.